# How to convert Byte Array In Java

Tags: java, jce

File encryption i got a 64 length byte array key. I am Using RSA algorithm for encrypting  AES key. I want to send encrypted key to client via email.To send 64 length byte array is tedious task.How to send  these encrypted key to client and decrypt these key.

Comment: In what way is it tedious? How do you send it? As text or as binary attachment? There is a tutorial from IBM on crypto: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-sec1/

Comment: As a text.after getting this key value the client can decrypt the file.Is any way to convert it into a alpha numeric string or integer value if any?

Comment: I suggest Base64 encoding. This will encode any byte array into ASCII, so you can send it as text and on the client read it to a byte array again. See here: http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/base64_encoding_with_jdk_1 (just one example of many)

Comment: after encoding using Base64, string length  will increases as per the size of key...in my example it is 174 length.how to send these key to client? After getting these value how they enter this into text field for decryption.

Comment: You said, you send it as text. Yes, Base64-encoding will change the size, that is ok. Just add it in the email text like you would do with a PGP-Key. Users on the other end can put it into the text field simply via copy&paste from their email client to your decryption application.